# Node javascript recurse out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I'm doing a simple recurse with node to generate all the strings of 10 characters.
I've a memory leak during execution.
The code is below.
Any ideas ?

I think it may be linked to the console.log(word) line.
Without this line, the code seems to work.
However, instead if printing the result to the screen, my final goal is to achieve an http request with the generated word. I've tried that without screen printing and it generates an out of memory as well.

```
var char = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
    'h',
    'i',
    'j',
    'k',
    'l',
    'm',
    'n',
    'o',
    'p',
    'q',
    'r',
    's',
    't',
    'u',
    'v',
    'w',
    'x',
    'y',
    'z',
    ' ',
    '\''
];


function recurseWord( keyword ){

    if ( keyword.length >= 10 ){
        return null ;
    }
    else{
        for ( var index = 0 ; index < char.length ; ++index){

            keyword = keyword + char [index];

            console.log (keyword);

            recurseWord (keyword) ;

            keyword = keyword.substring(0, keyword.length-1);

        }
    }
    return null ;
}

var keyword = "";
recurseWord(keyword);
```

Comment: My quick maths tells me there's 296 trillion combinations.  Are you sure you want to do a web request for each one?

Comment: hum, it's quite a lot ;-). I'll probably limit to few characters. Also, I think I'll update the code to stop the recursion when the request result is negative. My question was a general one though, for my knowledge ;-)

Comment: Actually, how long did it take to run out of memory?  I ran your code and it seems to be working so far (with console.log).  Also, in theory it should work fine.  You are only 10 scopes deep at max.  What version/OS of node?

Comment: Node version 5.2.0. It crashes after 10 secs. It goes till aaaaaaakjl more or less ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to move the recursive call out of the for loop. Otherwise the loop will never exit because `index` will stay at 0.

```
function recurseWord( keyword ){

        console.log (keyword);
    if ( keyword.length >= 10 ){
        return null ;
    }
    else{
        for ( var index = 0 ; index < char.length ; index++){

            keyword = keyword + char [index];

            console.log ("index "+index);

        }
        keyword += recurseWord(keyword.substring(0, keyword.length-1));
    }
    return null ;
}
```

Comment: You are wrong unfortunately. I want to generate all combinations of 10 characters. Your algorithm just generate one single 26 characters string. Also, your algorithm does not use recursion properly. In fact, you are just doing one single recursive call that will meet directly the stop condition.

Comment: What is your expected result? 
['abcdefghij','bcdefghijk','cdefghijkl', .. ]

Comment: I fail to see why you need recursion for this. Do you expect 28^10 results?

Answer (score 0):

As to why you are running out of memory I can't say exactly but you could try this instead. As a note, I am not running out of memory running this (been running a few minutes).

***NOTE: This will lock your machine (400+ trillion operations)***

```js
var inputArr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ".split("").concat("\'");

function run(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

function recurse(index, recursed) {
  if (recursed === undefined)
    recursed = "";
  if (recursed.length >= 10)
    return;

  for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    run(recursed + index[i]);
    recurse(index, recursed + index[i]);
  }
}

recurse(inputArr);
```

Comment: Ok I guess my code was not wrong because I have the same error with your code. It crashes quickly when I'm reaching string "aaaaaaarfs" (it depends of the execution : sometimes it crashes quicker, sometimes slower).

Comment: I do not have this issue with either.  Currently, I am running on v5.5.0 Windows x64 version.  I let it run to aaaacaaaaa+ and had no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Jeannot, you must be funny enough, you can't generate them that way.

That's 26 to the power of 10 = 141'167'095'653'376 operations (i.e. ~half a million billion operations).

You have to measure it out, even with C/C++ (which is rather low and near cpu level), you should run below 1 billion operations only (by the power of CPUs in present year 2016).